# Como incluir funções ou procedimentos no Pascal através de um arquivo já existente?

Tags: pascal

Sou novo em Pascal e estou procurando como chamar funções ou procedimentos de um arquivo já existente no Pascal.

Existe uma função em Julia chamada `include('filename.jl')` em que eu adiciono funções já escritas num bloco de notas feitas anteriormente para que eu possa usá-las enquanto estou executando o compilador.

Gostaria de saber se existe tal aplicação no Pascal. Se sim, como que eu devo escrever no arquivo de texto? Poderia me dar um exemplo claro de sua aplicação? Estou há boas horas procurando como fazer isso, mas nada satisfatório.

Comment: Usando diretivas? `{$I nomearquivo}` ou `{$INCLUDE nomearquivo}`?

Comment: Vi um exemplo na internet, mas não entendi muito bem. Poderia me explicar o que o comando faz (ou me dar um link que explique) e como usar e quando usar? E sua funcionalidade?

Comment: Eu acho que entendi agora. O que você quer é usar uma biblioteca de funções externas ao seu arquivo. Você quer fazer um módulo bonito que realiza uma tarefa, mas você quer usar funções e procedimentos externos ao seu arquivo, é isso?

Comment: @GabrielOshiro Sim!! Exatamente isso que o Julia faz. =) Não é necessário programar as funções no terminal para usa-las, mas

Comment: Então acho que o que você quer está descrito na minha segunda resposta. Tenta rodar o exemplo que eu postei do jeito que está, se funcionar, tenta adaptar para o seu programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu vou responder de novo com uma idéia mais clara do que eu *acho* que você quer.

Você pode usar um arquivo de bibliotecas de funções e procedimentos. Por exemplo:

**Biblioteca** - com uma única função que extrai uma substring `SubStr`

```
library subs; 

function SubStr(CString: PChar;FromPos,ToPos: Longint): PChar; cdecl; 

var 
  Length: Integer; 

begin 
  Length := StrLen(CString); 
  SubStr := CString + Length; 
  if (FromPos > 0) and (ToPos >= FromPos) then 
  begin 
    if Length >= FromPos then 
      SubStr := CString + FromPos - 1; 
    if Length > ToPos then 
    CString[ToPos] := #0; 
  end; 
end; 

exports 
  SubStr; 

end.
```

**Usando a biblioteca**

```
program testsubs; 

function SubStr(const CString: PChar; FromPos, ToPos: longint): PChar; 
  cdecl; external ’subs’; 

var 
  s: PChar; 
  FromPos, ToPos: Integer; 
begin 
  s := ’Test’; 
  FromPos := 2; 
  ToPos := 3; 
  WriteLn(SubStr(s, FromPos, ToPos)); 
end.
```

Comment: Se essa resposta é mais plausível, me avisa que eu deleto a outra.

Comment: Consegui, misteriosamente, fazer funcionar. Ainda bem que não preciso ser um "teórico da computação". rs
Usando o que você fez eu precisei, além de definir a biblioteca, precisei pegar o arquivo da biblioteca ("libNomeDaBiblioteca.so) e colocar na biblioteca do meu sistema operacional (que no caso é : /usr/lib). Vide [link](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse56.html#x267-28200012.3).
Também consegui fazer de outra maneira mais simples, usando as units que vocês fizeram no inicio, mas seguindo o [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_units.htm).

Comment: Boa sorte na continução do seu projeto ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar diretivas de compilação. Exemplo retirado da documentação do [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu40.html#x47-460001.2.40).

```
unit testi;

interface

{$I *}

implementation

end.
```

Neste exemplo, o compilador vai procurar um arquivo chamado `testi` ou `testi.pp` e vai "colar" onde está a diretiva de compilação `{$I}`.

O compilador vai procurar o seu arquivo nos seguintes lugares:

- local especificado na diretiva
- no diretório atual
- todos diretórios especificados nos diretório de busca (você pode adicionar diretórios ao diretório de busca usando a opção `-Fi` da linha de comando)

Alguns cuidados a serem tomados:

- O nome da `unit` tem que ser o mesmo nome do arquivo.
- Você pode incluir arquivos dentro de outros arquivos, mas não infinitamente. O numero máximo é restrito pelo numero de descritores de arquivos disponíveis ao compilador Free Pascal.
- Contrariamente ao Turbo Pascal, você pode incluir `cross blocks`. Isto é, um arquivo pode abrir um `Begin` e em um outro arquivo a ser incluído fechar o bloco com `End`.

Comment: Eu fiz e deu o erro da [imagem](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20r0w7&s=8).


Aqui está uma [imagem](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6y0f1g&s=8#.VUhihuRVK1E) do meu arquivo que estou adicionando. 


Tem algum problema? Quais? Eu fiz como disse e deu varios erros.

Comment: Ah! Mudei a pasta para a Área de Trabalho, mas apresentou o erro, como pode ver.

Comment: @Renan Qual o nome do seu arquivo? e qual o nome do arquivo que você quer incluir?

Comment: O nome é Func.pas. Eu estou tentando compilar com um compilador Pascal e não de Delphi.
Não quero no meu arquivo principal os procedimentos e funções que eu usarei no meu programa. Desejo, então, ter um arquivo com essas funções (que no caso é a Func.pas, mas pode ser um arquivo totalmente sem sentido, pois nunca vi isso feito no Pascal, mas somente em Julia e fiz igual ou semelhante ao Julia). Venho tentando, de alguma forma, fazer o que vc e o colega baixo tem dito, mas estou completamente perdido, visto que estou falando de Pascal e não Delphi (não entendo delphi).

Comment: @Renan: vi a imagem que você colocou. O nome do arquivo é `Func.pas`, mas o nome da unit é apenas `Func`. O erro diz que o símbolo `.` (do `.pas`) não é válido ali e de fato não o é. Mude a primeira linha da unit para `unit Func;`

Comment: Tentei fazer e não deu certo. Eu tenho o Geany e o FPC (por terminal) pra compilar. Eu não ligo em usar qualquer um dos dois pra compilar, mas acho o Geany mais claro, apesar de não existir diferenças significativas entre eles.
Aquilo do Func.pas foi uma tentativa minha em tentar deixar o arquivo num formato de Delphi, mas acho que não vai dar certo.
Vou postar o arquivo que eu estou usando e se vc conseguir resolver isso, acho melhor, mas eu não sei. '-'
[Func.pas](http://www.filedropper.com/func) 
[Func.](http://www.filedropper.com/semttulo_1)
. Esses são os arquivos dos programas.

Comment: Virei o arquivo de ponta cabeça e nada. =S Continua dando erro no nome. Acho que pode ser até o compilador que não entende ObjectPascal (que é o que vc disse ser a linguagem do Delphi, se não me engano).

Comment: Copiei a programação inteira do [link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal) e ainda não compilou tanto no terminal como no Geany.

Answer (score 2):

Uma aplicação em Delphi é dividida em **units**. Cada **unit** é um arquivo de código fonte em linguagem **ObjectPascal** (não é o pascal padrão), onde podem ser declarados diversas construções de linguagem, como tipos e procedimentos isolados. Para que uma **unit** possa ter acesso a construções declaradas em outra, existe uma sessão chamada `uses`. Esta sessão contem a lista de quais **units** devem ser consultadas para que os símbolos sejam reconhecidos e resolvidos pelo compilador.

Assim, se existem duas **units** declaradas (`Unit1` e `Unit2`), para que `Unit1` faça uso dos símbolos existentes em `Unit2`, faz-se como colocado a seguir.

**Unit1**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Unit2;

type
  TClasse1 = class(TClasse2)
  end;

implemetation

end.
```

**Unit2**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  TClasse2 = class
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Neste exemplo, `Unit2` declara um tipo chamado `TClasse2` que será utilizado em `Unit1` para declarar um outro tipo, chamado `TClasse1`.

`Unit1` precisa existir em um arquivo chamado `Unit1.pas` e `Unit2` precisa existir em um arquivo chamado `Unit2.pas`.

Comment: @Renan pensando bem, eu acho que o que você quer é o que o AlexSC respondeu... você cria um módulo externo e usa `uses` para chamar a referência. +1 pra vc Alex ;-)

Comment: Tá... não entendi nada, pois não sei onde colocar isso no meu código. Conheço nada de Delphi, pensei em colocar Delphi de tags, pois pensei em chamar a atenção daqueles que sabem Delphi que talvez poderiam responder minha pergunta sobre Pascal. Estou me esforçando aqui, mas isso é em Delphi certo? Isso pode ser implementado num compilador de Pascal? Se sim, como? O que eu devo fazer?

Comment: @Renan: se pode ou não ser implementado em um compilador de Pascal vai depender deste compilador. Por exemplo, se for um Turbo Pascal ou um FreePascal, sim, os conceitos são esses mesmos. Se for algum outro, seria necessário saber se ele é absolutamente Pascal padrão ou já sofreu evoluções. De qual compilador estamos falando?